# comparing today's date and input date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, string-comparison

I'm trying to get a user's input and storing that in a variable that I can use to compare to today's date. If it equals to Today's date it will output a message else it would just output the data.

```
<script>
  let month  = [];
  let day   = [];
  let year = [];

  let monthInput  = document.getElementById("month");
  let dayInput   = document.getElementById("day");
  let yearInput = document.getElementById("year");

  let messageBox  = document.getElementById("display");

  function insert ( ) {
  month.push( monthInput.value );
  day.push( dayInput.value );
  year.push( yearInput.value );
  celebrate();
  }

  function  celebrate() {

  // Show output
   messageBox.innerHTML = "";

    let q = new Date();
    let m = q.getMonth();
    let d = q.getDay();
    let date = new Date(m, d);
  //compares dates
    if( m == month && d == day ){
      messageBox.innerHTML = `Happy Birthday!`;
    }else{
      console.log(date);
      messageBox.innerHTML += `Your birthday is ${month}/${day}`;
    }
  }
</script>
```

I only got an output of the else statement.

Comment: `m == month` One of those is an array and the other is not so they will never be equal. Same for `d == day`.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that `getDay` returns the day of the week (5 = Friday) and that `getMonth` is 0-based, so May is 4 instead of 5.

So, if you want to compare months and days to the values a user would input, you should use `date.getMonth() + 1` as month and `date.getDate()` as day.

If you want to use the value of an input, just use the value property. e.g. `document.getElementById("month").value`

In short:

```
var d = new Date();
if (
  Number(document.getElementById("month").value) === (d.getMonth() + 1) &&
  Number(document.getElementById("day").value) === d.getDate()
) {}
```